# Mongoose not saving any data to local mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

so I'm currently trying to develop a mmorpg from scratch and got up to trying to save users from my client side (I'm using game maker studio). Im using robomongo as my Mongodb management tool.
My client connects just fine to my server and im able to take in a username and password but nothing is being saved to the database i created. Here is my user.js file:

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');


var userSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, unique:true},
    password: String,

    sprite:String,

    current_room: String,
    pos_x:Number, 
    pos_y:Number
});

userSchema.statics.register=function(username,password,cb){

    var new_user=new User({
        username: username,
        password: password,

        sprite: "spr_Hero",

        current_room:maps[config.starting_zone].room,
        pos_x:maps[config.starting_zone].start_x,
        pos_y:maps[config.starting_zone].start_y,
    });
    //save user to database
    new_user.save(function(err){
        if(!err){
            cb(true)
        }else{
            cb(false);
        }

    });

};
userSchema.statics.login=function(username,password,cb){

    //findOne searched db - mongodb specific method
    //searches db using json objects (cant do that in other sql/mysql)

    User.findOne({username:username},function(err,user){
        if(!err && user){
            if(user.password==password){
                cb(true,user);
            }else{
                cb(false,null);
            }

        }else{
            //error||user doesnt exist
            cb(false,null);
        }

    })
};


//export into gloabl space of our application
module.exports=User=gamedb.model('User',userSchema);
```

and here is my mongodb.js file. I configured the database location in my config.js. Im just using my local ip. Any help on fixing this would be great thanks!

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise=global.Promise; 


module.exports=gamedb=mongoose.createConnection(config.database);
```

Comment: Just incase it might be of use im running v 3.4.4 of Mongodb and v1.0 robomongo

Comment: Just bumping this so the question doesn't get lost.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using MongoDB 3.4 which is not supported by Robomongo currently, but it will be soon. You can follow this ticket for updates: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250
Note: I am one of the contributors of Robomongo.

Comment: Woah, this is such a great help. We had thought that could of been an issue but we thought the update may of already been released for it.
Do you know a place to download older versions? We had looked for it before and couldn't find one. Also what about replacing RoboMongo with something like MongoChef?

Comment: Older versions of Robomongo are here: https://robomongo.org/download. We are planning to release a beta tomorrow on this ticket: https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1250 which will immediately enable MongoDB 3.4 support.